# Laravel 5.4: Eloquent sync() not using model's mutator or attribute casting?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

[Mutators and Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators)

I have a model with a 'modify' attribute.
The model uses a set attribute. This is because the storage is held as boolean, but the attribute is managed via a select (because the FE options available are three-state: [none | modify | access ] where 'none' is not stored BE.

Storage is as follows (mysql):

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| prop_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| modify      | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 1       |       |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The model uses the following mutator method to translate 'modify' to true.

```
public function setModifyAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['modify'] = ($value === "modify");
}
```

A typical collection being passed over for sync() is as follows:

```
$properties = 
Collection {
  #items: array [
    1 => array [
      "modify" => "modify"
    ]
    7 => array [
      "modify" => "access"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am then calling sync for the properties as follows:

```
$this->properties()->sync($properties);
```

However, the setModifyAttribute() is not being accessed from sync().

Alternatively, using values 'true' and 'false' sync() appears to be ignoring the Attribute Casting hints.

```
protected $casts = ['modify' => 'boolean'];
```

Should I run some sort of closure over the collection instead? I would prefer to use a model-centric process.

Comment: Did you find the answer ?

Comment: @danialdezfooli, honestly - no. I just worked around it in the end.

Answer (score -4):

from the laravel documentation the method setXXXAttribute is just like this

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
    }
```

so i guess your code should be  modified :

```
public function setModifyAttribute($value){
($value==="Modify"):$this->attributes['modify']=1?$this->attributes['modify']=0;

}
```

maybe it is wrong ,good luck

Comment: You are correct in that I got the method wrong, however sync() doesn't call the attributes anyway.

Comment: i think ,the method sync() is used to sync the attributes in provide table. and  your model relation is Many To Many?